# Logging into a macOS system from a Linux system gives a locale-related warning

Tags: terminal, homebrew, unix, ssh

I'm logging into a Mac laptop from a Linux laptop over ssh - so I have an ssh daemon on the Mac side, and I'm using the /usr/bin/ssh client on the Linux side.

I consistently get:

```
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.utf8): No such file or directory
```

Logging in from the mac to the same mac, does not give the warning; it's only when I log in from a Linux system that I get that warning.

Putting the following in my Mac's .bash_profile does *not* help:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Running localedef on the Mac gives the following error:

```
bash-5.1# /usr/bin/localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
Can't open UTF-8: No such file or directory
```

But I do appear to have an en_US.UTF-8 locale on the Mac:

```
bash-5.1# pwd
/usr/share/locale
bash-5.1# ls -ld en_US.UTF-8
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  wheel  256 Jan  1  2020 en_US.UTF-8
```

What do I need to do to log into the Mac from Linux without a warning and get my preferred locale set?

I'm using homebrew's /usr/local/bin/bash if that matters.

Thanks!

Comment: But what locale *is* the Mac using?

Comment: Linux recognizes both `UTF-8` and `utf8`, but macOS only recognizes the `UTF-8` spelling. I can't figure out how to teach it about an alias. On Big Sur, there's a file `/usr/share/locale/locale.alias`, but it's protected by SIP and I don't know if there's another location where you can put the same information.

Comment: If you rewrite the value in your `.bash_profile`, your locale choice will take effect in interactive sessions, but you'll still have the error message when bash starts (assuming the Homebrew bash is your login shell).

Comment: @MarcWilson echo $LC_ALL gives en_US.UTF-8

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Yes, Homebrew bash is my login shell, and it appears in /etc/shells.

Comment: @MarcWilson I just realized that LC_ALL is coming from my .bashrc. The locale on my Mac is "C".

Comment: Why did you change the locale on the Mac?  It should be using en_US.UTF-8 by default.  You shouldn't be setting the locale in the shell init on either side without a very good reason.

Comment: @MarcWilson Logging in over SSH normally carries the locale settings from the client.

Comment: @MarcWilson I do not know why the locale is C on the Mac.  I did not do anything intended to change it.  I did, however, install homebrew and some vim plugins.

Comment: I don't know if macOS supports it, but you might be able to create an alias in /etc/locale.alias (see [this AskUbuntu Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883622/alias-for-locale-or-add-new-locale)).

Comment: This is odd.  The Mac's System Preferences > Language & Region > General believes I'm in English and the United States. But if I start an iTerm2, I get C.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' That's very different than explicitly setting them in a shell init.  That hasn't been necessary for years.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to:

```
LC_ALL=C ssh remote-mac.example.com
```

And the Mac was happy.